# who to control back button available on android phone

Tags: android, hardware, back-button

Is it possible to control hardware button available on back button? I just want this back button to work same as button in our codes. So i need guidance of you people, if it is possible.I am using following code to send sms and i actually want to control back from the activity i get by using this code:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
    intent.putExtra("sms_body", smsValue);
    intent.setData(sendSmsTo);

    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: u can override onBackPressed() in activity

Answer (score 0):

Override this method.

```
    @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: thanks..one more thing i won't to ask..if i am using intent to send sms and from that sms activity.. i want to control back button

Answer (score 0):

override onBackPressed() in activity :-

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      // your custom code

        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

dont forget to handle `super.onBackPressed();` or you will not be able to exit activity

Comment: thanks..one more thing i won't to ask..if i am using intent to send sms and from that sms activity.. i want to control back button

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      // your custom code
           if(somthing)
              {
                  //do what you want
              }
            else
             {
                super.onBackPressed();
             }
    }
```